# Неправильно описано условие цикла

Tags: c++, vector, for

[image: Задание:]

Перевод задания : найти x используя формулу, с точностью задаваемой пользователем, значение a , p ввести с клавиатуры.

Вот мой код на плюсах:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    float precision = 0, a = 0, p = 0;
    int counter = 0, n = 1;
    std::vector<float> vec_x = {1, 1};
    std::cout << "Enter a value of precision : " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> precision;
    std::cout << "Enter a value of a : " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Enter a value of p : " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> p;
    for (counter; abs(vec_x[counter] - vec_x[n]) < precision; counter++)
    {
        vec_x.push_back(vec_x[n] / pow(p, 2) * (pow(p, 2) - 1) + 1 / 2 * (p + 1) * a / pow(vec_x[n], p) - (1 / 2) * (p + 1) * pow(vec_x[n], p) / p);
        n++;
        std::cout << vec_x[n] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Как всё должно было работать: создаётся вектор x-ов, создаются переменные, в них записываем значения с клавиатуры, цикл проверяет условие: |x1 - x2| > precision, пока условие верно находит следующий x, выводит на экран, проверяет условие уже для нового x и так пока не выйдет с цикла.
Но программа проходит один раз и после этого выходит. Отладчик показывает, что 0.888889 < 0.0001 при вводе данных: 0.0001 , 2 , 3. Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно написать условие цикла.

Comment: непонятно: 1. зачем вам 2 счётчика(counter и n)? 2. для чего нужен вектор? Предыдущее значение можно хранить в переменной float.

Comment: Один счётчик для формулы и для вывода, а второй - для условия, а вектор нужен для хранения всех предыдущих x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вместо abs, нужно использовать fabs или [std::abs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs), abs - только для целочисленных.
2. Условие в цикле — это условие продолжения, а не условие выхода. Поэтому нужно проверять, что разница больше необходимой точности: `fabs(a-b)>precision`
3. У вас какая-то проблема с формулой, мало того, что вы забыли большие скобки(которые квадратные), так и то, что я смог распарсить с этой картинки, не даёт корректного результата.

Воспользуюсь итерационным алгоритмом из [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F_n-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <tuple>

double solve(double a, double p, double precision) {
    double prev, cur = 1;
    do {
        std::tie(prev, cur) = std::make_tuple(cur, ((p-1) * cur + a/std::pow(cur, p-1)) / p);
    } while (std::abs(cur - prev) > precision);

    return cur;
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас всё исправлю спасибо больше

Comment: В `<cmath>` есть перегруженные `std::abs()` для типов с плавающей точкой. [Пример](https://ideone.com/Gvd4hH).

Comment: Это да, есть там такой алиас, добавил в ответ)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, всё работает